# Mid-loop: Coming Soon

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

**Rules of Mid-loop**:

1. Draw a single loop passing through all of the black dots.
2. The loop may not branch off, intersect, or move diagonally.
3. The loop cannot bend at the black dot.
4. Each black dots denotes the mid-point of the line segment passing through it.

---

The standard Mid-loop rules apply. This puzzle is a teaser for my upcoming small puzzle contest.

[image]

Comment: Can lines only bend at the middle of a cell?

Comment: Does every line segment have to have a dot in the middle?

Comment: (I _think_ the answer to the question I just asked has to be no, because there are 23 dots, which is an odd number, and line segments have to alternate between E-W and N-S, which means a closed loop can't have an odd number of line segments. But I might be confused somehow...

Comment: Yes, lines only bend at the middle of a cell (like Masyu for example). And no, it may be possible that a line segment has no dot in the middle. In addition, here is the rules from Nikoli, with an example too :D https://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/mid-loop.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The finished grid:

> [image]

Progress Screenshots:

> [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]

Comment: Nicely done! :) Tbf, going from the last screenshot to the final solution might be the trickiest part of the puzzle, so it's a worthwhile to add some small explanation here.

Comment: @athin That's true. I will try to add some explanation when I have some time!

Comment: This was a fun puzzle. For me the "a-ha" moment from the last screenshot was rot13("vs gur ybbfr raq va pbyhza frira jrag evtug, vg jbhyq sbez na bqq ahzore bs ybbfr raqf va gur obggbz-evtug ertvba, juvpu vf vzcbffvoyr gb gvr hc.")